# Port already in use Issue..In .netcore MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to .netcore_MVC. I just copy paste the whole project and trying to alter the new one for my learning process. old one is running properly,but when I try to run my pasted project it shows "port '63854' already in use".

[image: Image of error]

Using some solutions I tried to change Launch browser's Local host number under Debug under Properties.

[image: Attached picture here]

But still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you updated the port number in Program.cs within the BuildWebHost Method?

Try to do this and then rebuild the solution.